# Wordpress JS Conflict: Inserting JS via custom post disables all JS on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using Savant themeto build a website, I use the following JS code on some pages (using Custom Fields, I use a field name "example" then assign JS in value) to get list of properties by calling an API and receiving JSON data.

JS Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bedstax.com/realtorData/featuredCommunities.php?state=FL&area=Bonita Springs%20/%20Estero"></script>
//-->
<script type="text/javascript">

var state = 'FL';
var area = 'Bonita Springs / Estero';
var idx = '583';
var agent = '1212';
var domain = 'xxx';

function setCommunity(community,communityName) {

    var cookieSet = window.state + "::" + window.area + "::" + window.idx + "::" + window.agent + "::" + window.domain + "::" + community + '::' + communityName;

    document.cookie='idxCookie=' + cookieSet + '; path=/';
    document.location.href = '/featured-communities-info';
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"http://bedstax.com/realtorData/newFeatComm.php?state=" + window.state + "&area=" + window.area + "&idx=" + window.idx,
        dataType: 'JSONP', // Notice! JSONP <-- P
        success:function(json){
            $('.output').html(json);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
});

</script>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

Removing the custom field enables all javascript, but this piece of code works. Is there something wrong with what I'm doing because it disables all JS on the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the JS console - if it disabled all JS on the page there may be an exception thrown somewhere

Comment: this is what it says in JS console: 
Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function    (in jquery.min.js:16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue by just upgrading jquery version from 1.5.1 to 1.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you include jquery, run the code below.

```js
var state = 'FL';
var area = 'Bonita Springs / Estero';
var idx = '583';
var agent = '1212';
var domain = 'xxx';

function setCommunity(community,communityName) {

    var cookieSet = window.state + "::" + window.area + "::" + window.idx + "::" + window.agent + "::" + window.domain + "::" + community + '::' + communityName;

    document.cookie='idxCookie=' + cookieSet + '; path=/';
    document.location.href = '/featured-communities-info';
}


jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"http://bedstax.com/realtorData/newFeatComm.php?state=" + window.state + "&area=" + window.area + "&idx=" + window.idx,
        dataType: 'JSONP', // Notice! JSONP <-- P
        success:function(json){
            $('.output').html(json);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error");
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

Comment: If you get an error with .on using jquery, you probably need a newer version of jquery.

Comment: I will use latest version and try

Comment: Unfortunately adding a newer version of jquery does not fix the issue, I've added the latest version
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: hmm, make sure to remove the old script reference. The code above works as you can see. Is there a different js error in the console?

Comment: Now there's a new one: 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: Does it seem like the error is coming from something in jquery itself? It's possible that upgrading to latest jquery has broken some other part of wordpress.

Comment: .on became available in jquery 1.7 I believe. You can always try a lower version because you were on 1.5 which is pretty old.

Comment: Reverting back to 1.5 brought back the old error :(

Comment: Its easy enough to switch them, maybe try 1.8. 
and make sure you haven't introduced any bugs in code changes you have made! :)